# Как поменять имя атрибута у элемента?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть много тегов `<img>` и у некоторых из них вместо `data-src="путь/к/картинке"` стоит `data-lazy="путь/к/картинке"`, и это ломает lazyload на моем сайте.

Как можно поменять название атрибута `data-lazy` на `data-src`?

Comment: Получите значение атрибута. Удалите его. Создайте новый с использованием старого значения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Значение из `data-lazy` задать в `data-src` и удалить `data-lazy`

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll('img[data-lazy]');

images.forEach((image) => {
  image.setAttribute('data-src', image.getAttribute('data-lazy'));
  image.removeAttribute('data-lazy');
});

images.forEach((image) => console.log(image));
```

```html
<img data-lazy="путь/к/картинке" />
<img data-lazy="путь/к/картинке" />
<img data-lazy="путь/к/картинке" />
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('img[data-lazy]');`

Comment: @Igor согласен, так красивее)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Скопировал весь код кроме вывода в консоль, data-lazy удаляет и переносит его значение корректно, только в итоге у меня почему то src а не data-src...

Comment: Проблема была в библиотеке lazyload, убрал и поменял местами и все заработало правильно =)